# Camera_info not working with libuvc_camera

Tags: ros, libuvc-camera, ros-hydro, logitech

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have setup libuvc_camera with a Logitech C902, here is the error I get:

```
CameraInfo/P resulted in an invalid position calculation (nans or infs)
```

does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/132701/camera_info-not-working-with-libuvc_camera/) by [AlphaOne](https://answers.ros.org/users/4021/alphaone/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2014-02-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had to run camera calibration
http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration/Tutorials/MonocularCalibration

---

Originally posted by [AlphaOne](https://answers.ros.org/users/4021/alphaone/) with karma: 141 on 2014-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0